# NIB view has not subviews when is loaded

Tags: xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xib, nib

I have a mainview working perfectly on iPhone.

Now, I'm working in a new version for iPad.

I created a new NIB file for iPad devices, and set the custom view for the same UIViewController. Create the same structure on the NIB and configurate the outlets and custom actions.

But when execute the application on the iPad simulator the subviews is not loaded. I check on code and the subviews is completely empty ... :SS

I try to addSubviews manually and it works but is not the solution of course ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view of the XIB file was not properly connected.